# Can't access .env file from current working directory

Tags: python, macos, dotenv

I am having an issue where a variable from my local `.env` file is not loading with the `load_dotenv` function.

I have confirmed that the `.env` file is in the same directory as my code, and using `os.getcwd()` shows that the working directory is correct.

However, it appears that `load_dotenv` is pulling my root file, since when I call `os.environ.keys()` it shows a bunch of root key/vals, i.e. `USER`, `PATH`, `SSH_AUTH_SOCK`, etc.

Solutions I have attempted via my SO research include wrapping the call around `find_dotenv()`, as well as explicitly passing in the file path using `sys.path[0]+'/.env'` but neither solution worked for me, and I am seeking alternative suggestions. Thanks in advance!

EDIT: min reproducible example

- from command line: `python3 -m venv venv_debug`
- create `test.py` as:

```
import os
import requests
from dotenv import load_dotenv, find_dotenv
load_dotenv(find_dotenv())
print(os.environ.keys())
```

create `SAMPLE.env` as:

```
MNEMONIC = 'one two three four five six seven eight nine ten eleven twelve '
```

[image]

This is what my folder looks like:

Running `python3 test.py` in the command line gives me a full list of base env variables, but not the `MNEMONIC` one I'm looking for.

Comment: Aren't you working in a python virtual environment?

Comment: `.env` is not generally used to replace the basic login-session environment variables, but only to add to them. If `USER`, `PATH`, `SSH_AUTH_SOCK`, etc. were deleted, that would cause a lot of tools to break; so what you're describing constitutes working-as-intended (unless the keys in `.env` _aren't_ being loaded, but I don't see this question saying either way; the only thing explicitly described is a problem is the fact that the default variables are still there, and... yes, they're supposed to be).

Comment: @CharlesDuffy understood, thanks for that explanation. Yes, the keys in .env are not being loaded

Comment: That being the case, could I request a [mre] I can run to see the problem myself? (In practice, this means I'll be spinning up a sandbox on https://repl.it/ and trying to cause the same problem there).

Comment: why are you expecting it to load a `SAMPLE.env` file? usually it is just a file called `.env` with no other parts to the filename, that matches how it is described [in the documentation](https://pypi.org/project/python-dotenv/) if you replace the name `SAMPLE.env` with just `.env` does it do what you are expecting?

Comment: How can I make a file with no name?

Comment: in terminal `mv SAMPLE.env .env` would work, in mac's finder you might need to edit the filename in the "more info" or "properties"  (by right clicking on the file, called different things in different os') for it to actually let you call it that.